# the version for buildings

Tags: meaning

What does the word "version" means in association with building? The whole sentence is this:

> In Canada, the version for existing buildings is owned and operated by BOMA Canada under the brand name 'Go Green'

Comment: The [sentence](http://www.bccassn.com/green_initiatives/greenglobes.html) is talking about the version **of the Green Globes scheme** which applies to existing buildings.

Comment: It's talking about a specific version of a standard or specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the word "version".  It refers to a program and not specifically to buildings.

> - version - "A particular form or variation of an earlier or original type" e.g. "He downloaded the latest version of the software from the Internet."

There must be more than one version of such project or program for buildings.  BOMA Canada owns and operates one of them under the brand name "Go Green".

Comment: Yes. It seems to be a version of Green Globe. Thank you. source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_surfaces_%28geoengineering%29#Green_Globes